# Java -jar is not running the tests compiled in the container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I can't run the tests in maven install because the database service isn't up to date, so I want to run the test when I run the .jar but it's not working

```
#
# Build stage
#
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-16 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY src /app/src
COPY pom.xml /app 
RUN mvn -f /app/pom.xml clean package -DskipTests=true
RUN mvn test-compile

#
# Package stage
#
FROM openjdk:16
COPY --from=build /app/target/bank-api.jar /usr/local/lib/bank-api.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/bank-api.jar"]
```

Comment: Tests don't get packaged in the jar.

Comment: Even if the tests were in the jar, why would simply running the jar execute them?

Comment: Understand. I imagined it would have the same behavior as a .war published in tomcat, because when the service goes up, the tests are automatically run.

Comment: What does "the database service isn't up to date" mean?

Comment: @tgdavies that the database service is not running.

Comment: I saw that the java -jar command doesn't run the tests, so I'll have to do something separate for the tests.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.